# structures in vs 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, struct

I already did code structures with eclipse and things worked out fine this way, but for msvs10 I still cannot work around getting the structures done properly.
I get the error message

"This declaration has no storage class or type specifier in C++".

(Googling it will return loads of different problems so I did not find mine...)

The file is pretty simple

Header

```
#ifndef MARCHING_CUBES_H_
#define MARCHING_CUBES_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/obj_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/search/kdtree.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d_omp.h>
#include <pcl/surface/marching_cubes_hoppe.h>
#include <pcl/surface/marching_cubes_rbf.h>
#include <vector>

#include <pcl/console/time.h>  

class MC{

public:
    int main (int argc, char** argv);
    struct MC_prop{
            int procedure;
            float isoLevel;
            int Gridresolution;
            float percentageExtendGrid;
            std::string filename;

            MC_prop(int pro, float iso, int grid, float perc, std::string name):procedure(pro),isoLevel(iso),Gridresolution(grid),percentageExtendGrid(perc),filename(name){};
            ~MC_prop(){};
          };

 };

#endif
```

and the way I wanna use it is to define a vector of the structure:

```
typedef struct MC::MC_prop MCprop;

std::vector<MCprop> files;
files.push_back(MCprop(1,1.0,1,1.0,"cubes2"));
```

But for the last line, the pushback , I will get the error mesage above.

Comment: What line does the error occur on (this is important)? Also, looks like you are looking more for `namespace` and not `class` by the way you are using `MC`.

Comment: as I wrote, I get the error while trying to push back the vector. the class is not yet done,  I will still add classes.

Comment: This code seems working on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L6EPpuWu0udUHpGD). Try changing `typedef struct MC::MC_prop MCprop;` to `typedef MC::MC_prop MCprop;` (remove `struct`)